# How can I use a Expression tree in an EF Where() clause with join?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, expression-trees

I'm trying to use expression tree in my linq to sql queries. and i use EF5

i wrote a method like this:

```
    private Expression<Func<Tbl1, bool>> Expr1()
    {              
        return tbl1 => tbl1.FSystemCode == (int)comboBoxSystemCode.SelectedValue;
    }
```

and my query is:

```
    private object bindingSourceTbl1_DataSourceBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        using (SampleDbEntities dbo = new SampleDbEntities())
        {

           return dbo.Tbl1.Join(dbo.Tbl2, x => x.Id, y => y.Tbl1Id, (x, y) => new { Tbl1 = x, Tbl2 = y }).Where(this.Expr1()).Where(a => a.Tbl2.Tbl6Id == (int)comboBoxTbl6.SelectedValue).Select(a => a.Tbl1).ToList();
        }
    }
```

but fails at runtime for this .Where(this.Expr1())

Please help me to write correct code.

Comment: What message does it give you when it fails?

Comment: This shouldn't compile, because `Join` produces `IQueryable<'a>` (anonymous type), so, next `Where` accepts `Expression<Func<'a, bool>>`. Please, show your *real* code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved my problem by this change and this work for me:

```
private object bindingSourceTbl1_DataSourceBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SampleDbEntities dbo = new SampleDbEntities())
    {

       return dbo.Tbl1.Join(dbo.Tbl2, x => x.Id, y => y.Tbl1Id, (x, y) => new { Tbl1 = x, Tbl2 = y }).Where(a => a.Tbl2.Tbl6Id == (int)comboBoxTbl6.SelectedValue).Select(a => a.Tbl1).Where(Expr1()).ToList();
    }
}
```

i think this must be true.